# PHP MySQL 'No such file or directory'

Tags: php, mysql

Recently I've bought webhosting at names.co.uk and I'm trying to set up something simple which will display the name from a table named Team if the id = 1.
This is my code

```
<?php 
$q = "SELECT * FROM `Team` WHERE id =1";

$result = mysql_query($q);

echo '<br />Query is send';
    echo '<br />Result is true';
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<br />tryed fetching row';
    if ($row === FALSE) {
        echo '<br />$row is not false.';
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo '<br />$name now is "' . $name . '"';
    }
    else {
        echo( mysql_error());
    }

echo $name;
    ?>
```

This is the output:

> Query is send Result is true tryed fetching rowNo such file or
>   directory

UPDATE:

I have changed to msqli:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `Team` WHERE id =1";

$result = mysqli_query($q);

echo '<br />Query is send';
    echo '<br />Result is true';
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<br />tryed fetching row';
    if ($row !== FALSE) {
        echo '<br />$row is not false.';
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo '<br />$name now is "' . $name . '"';
    }
    else {
        echo( mysqli_error());
    }

echo $name;
```

and now I'm getting this output:

> Query is send Result is true tryed fetching row $row is not false.
>   $name now is ""

Comment: mysql_* extension is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: mysql_* are deprecated functions and removed in php7 - use PDO or mysqli_* to replace

Comment: What version of php do you have? The mysql_* method is outdated, you should use mysql instead.

Comment: your if statement should be if ($row !== FALSE) {
      ...
    }
    else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

Comment: @JYoThI ^^I'd format that for easy reading haha

Comment: i think here you posted half error message only .

Comment: I've updated my post as it's still not fully working

Comment: inside the single quotes everything consider as string . you need to escape it properly .

Comment: You need to read the documentation on the mysqli_ API. Your updated code is missing arguments for a few of those functions.

Comment: change this line echo '<br />$name now is ' . $name; and let me know the answer @JordDuineveld

Comment: @JordDuineveld Change `$row !== FALSE` to `$row != FALSE`. `!=` compares the parameters value while `!==` compares the type of the parameters.

Comment: @lkdhruw I've done this but now it's not outputting anything after the "tryed fetching row"

Comment: @JYoThI still the same

Comment: @JordDuineveld `mysqli_query` require one more parameter as `mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`. see the doc http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to fist establish a connection. For example: `$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);`.

See this link on how to use MySQLi: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_connect.asp (but note that *w3schools is a bad resource, with outdated information and bad practices* - I'm only linking to it because this tutorial is basic and clear).

Be sure to check later, if you still haven't, on how to properly sanitize your queries. See this, for example: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score -3):

Use function:

```
$result = mysqli_query($q);
```

mysql_query() have been deprecated in PHP7 onwards.

Comment: removed in php7* it was deprecated ages ago